# Csrf verification failed - Django Rest and Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, python, django, backbone.js

I have started going through "Lightweight Django" https://github.com/lightweightdjango to learn more about Django and Client-Side JavaScript. During testing out the `LoginView` created using `Backbone.js` I get the `Forbidden(403) CSRF verification failed.Request aborted.` message, as pointed out in this post: [CSRF verification failing in django/backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552013/csrf-verification-failing-in-django-backbone-js) . 
First of all I thought of inserting `{% csrf_token %}` template tag in the form but when I do this the server is giving me a `POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0 - Method Not Allowed (POST) : /` message.

Since the AJAX `X-CSRFToken` request header is being set using `$.ajaxPrefilter()`, I can't figure out what the problem is.

When I am using httpie to perform POST requests using the superuser details, everything works just fine as in the following example:

```
 HTTP/1.0 200 OK
 Allow: POST, OPTIONS
 Content-Type: application/json
 Date: Mon, 11 Sep 2017 13:49:49 GMT
 Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.2
 Vary: Cookie
 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

 {
    "token" : some_value
 }
```

Making use of the console from the "Inspect Element" feature I get the following messages:

```
 Response headers:
   Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
   Content-Length: 0
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   Date: Mon, 11 Sep 2017 14:03:06 GMT
   Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.2
   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

 Request headers:
   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
   Connection: keep-alive
   Content-Length: 116
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   Cookie: csrftoken=some_value
   Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
   Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
```

I don't know if the `TemplateView` is to blame or I am missing something:

```
 urls.py:    
   from django.conf.urls import url,include
   from django.views.generic import TemplateView
   #from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

   from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

   from board.urls import router

   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^api-auth/', obtain_auth_token, name='api-login'),
       url(r'^api-root/', include(router.urls)),
       url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='board/index.html')),
   ]
```

Can someone explain what is actually going on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fore every POST request you need  to send CSRF token to  your django backend in Django weebasite u can fined ajaxSetup for your frontend (backbone.js). Just create new file ajaxSetup.js and past this code.

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
function sameOrigin(url) {
    // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + 
    '/') ||
    (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + 
    '/') ||
    // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
    !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
            // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
            // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

You can read about this in django official website [CSRF TOKEN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/)